# Smart switch mess. Ceiling Fan/ light

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, fans, smart-switch

I was hoping maybe i can get some help.

I recently moved to a new place. So i been doing alot of DYI and need help with this one. I changed our old fan to a new one but now the new one doesnt turn on... I triple checked the wiring on the fan and everything looks fine. Now the wiring on the wall I have never messed with but now I am asking myself if the issue is lying with the switch.. since its a different fan. Also there 2 wires in the Live is that okay? What I need to connect to make it work?
I was only able to add 1 picture so im putting links.
If anyone can help i will really appreciate it. Thanks in advanced

https://ibb.co/KNKt1Dv
https://ibb.co/zX5zcSS
https://ibb.co/NW5zLJB
https://ibb.co/BG4NJCn
https://ibb.co/t2jHLW3

Comment: What is that connection with the whites, black, and yellow(cable looking) wires?  I think you are not allowed to mark a non white(black) wire as white(neutral) at that size.

Comment: Careful - that Do Yourself In (DYI) is quite hazardous .vs. Do It Yourself (DIY.)

Comment: There is a yellow cable coming out of the ceiling at the fan.  How many wires are in it, and what colors are they?  There is a blue wire disappearing off the bottom of the fan picture.  What is it connected to?

Comment: @crip659 i have no idea honestly.

Comment: @jay613 the blue white and black cable connects from the remote to the motor

Comment: @jay613 also whats in the yellow is the ground wire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fan might be connected properly but the switch is not.  Notice where the little fan symbol is located on the switch.  That switched hot terminal has a white wire attached to it, and that wire hasn't been properly identified for use as a non grounded conductor.  NEC 200.7 does not allow white wires to be used in this manner.

Also, there is a black wire in use as a neutral pigtail, which is very unprofessional.

The yellow sheathing next to the switch is hiding a hijacked ground wire.  This could be extremely dangerous because it is evidence that the old fan was intentionally set up to use the ground wire as a circuit conductor. This is sometimes referred to as a "ground fault".

Here's what you've got in the switch box:

- Cable A - Power coming to the switch.
- Cable B - Power to other parts of the dwellling.
- Cable C - Switched power to the fan.

In Cable C, there is not an adequate number of circuit conductors to provide separate switching for a light and a fan.

Here is one solution:

1. Turn off the circuit breaker.
2. At the switch box, remove the wire nut for the white wires.
3. Remove the yellow sheathing.  You will find a bare copper wire inside.
4. The bare copper wire MUST be spliced to the other 2 bare copper wires.
5. Remove the white wire from the switch.
6. Move that white wire over to the other white wires and reset the wire nut.
7. (optional) To be able to turn on the fan and light at the same time, you might need to adjust the wiring at the new fan.  This might be related to the fan's blue wire but I can't tell just by looking at a photo.  Some fans use pull chains or remotes instead of wall switches.

Comment: Connected to the switch is 2 wires in L. 1 in the lighting 1 in the fan and 1 in the N also there a empty slot is that okay?..... i got a feeling this will have to be an electrician's job.... im gonna see if i can make a clear photo if thats okay

Comment: @Luckynico The white wire attached to the switch is much more dangerous than the double tapped L screw.  At best it will prevent the fan and light from functioning.  If you are working on those wires and don't realize the white wire is "Live" it can be a bad day.

Comment: https://ibb.co/N7tFSMK
https://ibb.co/L59292m

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/RAAgKHW4kZE?feature=share

Comment: I see something new.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay so i see the white wire is actually connected to a live not a neutral that means that black wire is wrong as well because its in the neutral. Im just worried if i mess with that whatever is put in wire twist will just mess everything up.                      Okay thank you

Comment: @Luckynico My updated answer should be more complete.

Comment: Okay thank you!. The black cable in N i can get rid of? For the fan..The blue one thats with the black and white is to send signal to the motor the box is the sensor for the remote... also this fan has no chain https://ibb.co/wpKj0Zg
https://ibb.co/bN7k36b

Comment: @Luckynico The pigtail to switch's "N" is in the right place, just the wrong color.  If you don't have a better replacement on hand I would leave that one alone for now, leaving it spliced to the white wires.

Comment: Its working thanks again...  im on my way to buy the white cable now

Comment: @Luckynico Remember to click the check mark to accept the answer above.  My local retailer sells 25 ft of white THHN wire for about $10.

Comment: Its a good price and the check mark is up..  wish i can pay for the service no way of private here just noticed. Thanks